# Can I specify video format and pixels orientation when using clive for downloading Youtube videos?

Tags: command-line, video

Can I specify video format and pixels orientation when using clive for downloading Youtube videos?

If yes, what is command?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following command for testing youtube (urls).

```
clive --format=best http:// yt-url
```

or

```
clive -f best http:// yt-url
```

It started downloading the video in .webm format (~ 1.8 times the size of default .flv format for my example).

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensive list of command line options available here, and it looks like some may answer your question (albeit, not exactly what you requested):

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/clive.1p.html

(.. in particular, it looks like the `--format` option and sub-section explaining how the provider has some control over what resolution and such that clive can utilize)

Here's a 720p/MP4 format download off of YouTube, but the Man shown above is essential as a reference, as the switch variables (fmt22/etc) can vary between providers or formats a lot:

```
$ clive -f fmt22 "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnaojlfdUbs"
Checking ...done.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15.1M  100 15.1M    0     0  1143k      0  0:00:13  0:00:13 --:--:-- 1149k
```

I verified the file played afterwards, and was properly saved in the format requested (1280x720p).

Comment: Can you give me an example, please? just how to download youtube videos in mp4 format at 720p quality

Comment: See the updated edit to my answer.  I'd recommend looking at the "FORMATS" section still, on the Man pages, so you can use `clive` on many different sites with ease.  The switch commands change a lot.